# Powershell - Does file exist on users machine | output specific file

Tags: powershell, export

I have the code below that checks if a file exists. If it does exist it writes one line of code, if it doesn't it writes another line of code.

```
# PowerShell  Checks If a File Exists
$WantFile = "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg"
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {Write-Host "Path is OK"} else {Write-Host "Path is wrong"}
```

I would like this code to create an output file for each of the write-hosts. If the path is true, create a text file in c:\true\true.txt and if path is wrong then creates a txt in path C:\false\false.txt.

I tried using out-file but couldn't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Write-Host` cmdlet writes it's output directly to the host application (in your case probably the console).

Simply remove it and pipe your strings directly to `Out-File`:

```
$WantFile = "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg"
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
# $FileExists is already either $true or $false
if ($FileExists) {
  # write to \true\true.txt
  "Path is OK" |Out-File C:\true\true.txt
} 
else {
  # write to \false\false.txt
  "Path is wrong" |Out-File C:\false\false.txt
}
```

---

As [TheMadTechnician notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479451/powershell-does-file-exist-on-users-machine-output-specific-file/43479593?noredirect=1#comment74015178_43479593), you can use `Tee-Object` if you want the string written to file *and* on the screen:

```
"Path is OK" |Tee-Object C:\true\true.txt |Write-Host
```

Comment: Of if he wants both... `"Path is OK" | Tee-Object C:\Path\To\True.log [-append] | Write-Host`

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what you want exactly...

To create a blank text file, just use

```
# PowerShell  Checks If a File Exists
$WantFile = "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg"
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {Write-Host "Path is OK"; Out-File C:\true\true.txt} else {Write-Host "Path is wrong"; Out-File C:\false\false.txt}
```

If the directory does not exist, swap `Out-File` with `new-item -force -type file`

To write text to the file, replace `;` with `|`. (If both of these are true, I believe you will need to create the item, and subsequently Out-File to the New-Item.)